# Maximize Time Varying function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to find the value of u that would maximize Ur(t) at a specific time for the set of functions below.

```
d(t) = 3 x d(t-1) + 4 x u(t-2) + k

Ur(t) = d(t) x u(t) - f x d(t)
```

Where f and k are constants

I’m a little rusty on my partial differential equations but his seems like a PDE to me.  Am I correct about that and is it solvable?  If so how, or what type of problem should I research?

For example can I just take the derivative of Pr with respect to p, hold all other variables constant and plug in the specific t value?  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is time continuous or discrete here? Also it looks like you need some kind of initial conditions on $d$ and $u$ to determine their values at time $t$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I believe the answer is discrete.  This is time-series data I'm working with, so dates with a unique value of each variable for each date.  And yes we would know the initial conditions for d and u, they would be the values on the first date in the time-series.

Comment: Oh also, is there a recurrence for $u$ as well? For example, how would you solve for $Ur(2)$? You'd need to know $u(2)$, for which there doesn't seem to be any value.